# Defining a classmethod outside of a class in Python

Tags: python, class, pygame, class-method, pygame-surface

I am making a game with Pygame where there are going to be many different screens. I am making a class called Screen that will have custom screens made for you. I need each screen to have different events and triggers though, so I can't just define one function in the class. I need separate functions for each screen which would mean that I need to define functions out side of the class definition for each screen. I don't know if this is possible but it would be good to know.
I have not gotten too far in yet but here is the code:

```
import pygame


class Screen:
    def __init__(self, size, bg_color, bg_image):
        self.size = size
        self.bg_color = bg_color
        self.bg_image = bg_image
        self.layers = []
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(self.size)

    # some code was taken out here to save space (it was just some x y width and height getters and setters)

    def add_item(self, item, layer=None):
        if layer is None:
            self.layers.append(item)
        else:
            self.layers.insert(layer, item)

    def remove_item(self, item):
        self.layers.remove(item)

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.fill(self.bg_color)
        self.screen.blit(self.bg_image)

        for item in self.layers:
            self.screen.blit(item, item.pos)
```

Comment: Maybe create a base class for the screens, and specialize each screen using inheritance? Please post a simplified example [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What did you do?

Comment: A solution can be to make one Screen class and create different functions in that class for each different screen. That's what I did for my game I made with PyGame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need each screen to have different events and triggers though

So you are searching for [Inheritance](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance). Read about [Inheritance and Polymorphism in Python](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/polymorphism)
Use `Screen` as a base class. Derive different classes from `Screen`, where you can implement different behavior:

```py
class Screen:
    def __init__(self, size, bg_color, bg_image):
        # [...]
  
    # [...]
```

```py
class Screen_1(Screen):
    def __init__(self, size, bg_color, bg_image):
        super().__init__(size, bg_color, bg_image)

    def my_method():
        # do something
        # [...]
```

```py
class Screen_2(Screen):
    def __init__(self, size, bg_color, bg_image):
        super().__init__(size, bg_color, bg_image)

    def my_method():
        # do something different
        # [...]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you could go about doing this:

1. One has already been given by NinjaFaraz. You would simply define functions outside of your class and create a dict or list with the available functions for each screen. You could even pass new functions during execution of your programme to dynamically enhance or reduce functionality of screens.
2. The second option is inheritance. This makes sense only if not too many types of screens are required. If that is the case, you could have a base class "Screen" with your basic functions and all other screens would inherit from that class. This makes sense if classes cannot gain/loose new functions dynamically.

Which of the two approaches is the better one depends on your specific circumstances and cannot be answered just yet with the information you provided.

Answer (score 0):

you can just creat a normal function outside of the class and pass it as one of the arguments to your class.